# System.InvalidOperationException: Can not set Visibility

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I created a window that can be closed only when you click outside of it. The code works very well here:

```
 protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         base.OnDeactivated(e);
         Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
 }
```

The only problem comes when the window is closed, for example, with `alt + f4`, in particular, takes this exception:

> You can not set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog, Close WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle or while you are on the closure of the Window.

How can I make sure to avoid it? Actually I've managed the exception with Try/Catch..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the window's `Deactivated` event is raised, the `Closing` event occurs (but, obviously, only if the window is closed on purpose by the user, e.g. by pressing `Alt+F4`). This means you can set a flag in the window's `Closing` event handler indicating that the window is currently being closed, meaning that the `Close()` method needs not be called in the `Deactivated` event handler:

```
    private bool _isClosing;

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
        _isClosing = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDeactivated(e);
        if (!_isClosing)
            Close();
    }
```